# Lua not fitting the hash causes compiling errors?

Tags: ipad, hash, lua, screen

I'm using a Lua developer environment called Lua on the iPad.
This hash works and compiles:

```
imgs = {readImage (spriteexample1, pos.x, pos.y), readImage(spriteexample2, pos.x,                
pos.y), readImage(spriteexample3, pos.x, pos.y), readImage(spriteexample4, pos.x,   
pos.y), readImage(spriteexample5, pos.x, pos.y), readImage(spriteexample6, pos.x, pos.y)}
```

(It cuts off on the second line after spriteexample4 on my screen.) The problem is, when I go on to the third line to add two more sprites as values, it tells me I must close the brackets on the first line. Any help?

Comment: Mistake with editing. Read again.

Comment: Please post a few of the lines of code that come before and after this segment.

Comment: There we go. Added it.

Comment: Probably, wrong symbol at the end of line 2 (e.g., CR)?

Answer (score 0):

If I copy the code you have and run it (after defining a bogus `readImage()` function and `pos={x=0,y=0}`), no problem, so there must be a weird character like perhaps a UTF-8 character that shows up normal in your editor but interpreter doesnt' like. Try opening the file in a tool like notepad++ with View | Show SYmbol | Show all characters.